# How to get userinfo in gorm hook(BeforeSave)?

Tags: go, go-gin

I add a field in global model which is UpdateBy and it save who updated the column ,  So I wanner to use Hook(gorm) to resolve But I Have no way to get current userinfo ( use gin )

```
type GVA_MODEL struct {
    ID        uint           `gorm:"primarykey"` 
    CreatedAt time.Time      
    UpdatedAt time.Time     
    DeletedAt gorm.DeletedAt `gorm:"index" json:"-"` 
    UpdatedBy string
}

func (g *GVA_MODEL) BeforeSave(db *gorm.DB) (err error) {
    fmt.Println("----------get user name/ID----------")
    return
}
```

Comment: Model `GVA_MODEL` isn't contain `name` attribute and `id` is `nil` because it not saved yet.

Comment: you can add it in your use case or service layer

Answer (score 1):

BeforeSave hook can only access fields from receiver: `g *GVA_MODEL`

So if you want to pass some extra values when executing BeforeSave, you can pass them via `db.Set` and `db.Get`.

```
// set user info from your gin controller...
db.Set("user_info", UserInfo{})

// access user_info from db instance's context
func (g *GVA_MODEL) BeforeSave(db *gorm.DB) (err error) {
    userInfo, _ := db.Get("user_info")
    fmt.Printf("----------get user name/ID----------: %v", userInfo)
    return
}
```